# Does select() use kernel timer( in jiffies ) or high res timer

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, sleep, linux-device-driver

I have a application in which I have to sleep for a very short time (in order of few micro seconds ). Fortunately my Linux kernel 2.8.* supports high res timers.

I have 2 options to sleep now

1. nanosleep
2. select() with a timeout.

I choose to use select() as it is quite portable. Does select() use the normal kernel timers ( jiffies) or it uses the hi res timers ?

Can this provide sleep functionality in order of microseconds ?

Comment: temme abt it. One of the perks of working in a huge firm :P

Comment: No, seriously, wha kernel are you using ?

Comment: Sorry. mis-interpreted your comment. Kernel version 2.6.18-128.1.6.el5

Comment: I think that version of the kernel already supports ``pselect`` and probably also your libc, so if you really want a high precision you can use it. One of the differences between ``select`` and ``pselect``is that the later offers more precision. Either than this, I actually don't know the answer to your question :\ ``select`` receives a ``struct timeval`` which has a component for microseconds, which leads me to believe that if your system supports it can offer microsecond precision.